# List sites within a SharePoint Site Collection

Tags: ios, objective-c, sharepoint, office365

Is there a way using the Office 365 API for iOS to list the sites created from SharePoint?

I've seen that it offers an iOS API for folders and files from SharePoint Online, but I don know if it covers also my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about the sites from a Site Collection?

Comment: Yes @BlackFrog, about Site Collections.

Comment: You should expand on your question. For example provide a link to the Office 365 API that you found.  From the little I know, Site Collection is on administrative site of things therefore they might not provide that kind of API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to use the Office 365 API to list all sites created from SharePoint. It doesn't matter you use the iOS SDK or do the calls yourself.

However, you might be able to use the SharePoint 2013 REST API. You just need to construct the calls yourself in Objective-C without any SDK to help you abstract away the low-level details. This link seems to have what you're looking for.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113528/what-is-the-rest-endpoint-url-to-get-list-of-site-collections